# Forcing a PowerShell pipline to end

Tags: .net, multithreading, powershell

I have a module that is supposed to run 8 commands in an async way,
each command will query the status of a different service.

One of the service queries occasionally will get a timeout (60 Seconds, by default).
I do not wish to wait that long, since my module is recurrent in shorter intervals.

I'm using 'WaitAny()' and defined the timeout to 10000ms (10 Seconds).
When the 'WaitAny()' timeout will take effect the $h variable will have a value of '258'.
That is when I want to force the pipline to quit.
I have used 'BeginStop()', But it seems it won't do anything.
After I have issued a 'BeginStop()' it will linger for the rest of the 60 seconds and will not continue.

How can I forcefully make the pipeline to end, and proceed.

```
$pool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1,8,$sessionstate,$Host)
$pool.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"
$pool.ApartmentState = "STA"
$pool.Open()
$res = @()
$i = 0
foreach ($CurrService in $Blocks) {
    $pipeline = [System.Management.Automation.PowerShell]::Create()
    $pipeline.RunspacePool = $pool
    [void]$pipeline.AddScript($ScriptBlock).AddArgument($CurrService.Service).AddArgument($CurrService.Command)
    $pipelines.Add($pipeline)
    $job = $pipeline.BeginInvoke()
    $jobs.Add($job)
    $handles.Add($job.AsyncWaitHandle)
    $i++
}
while ($pipelines.Count -gt 0) {
    $h = [System.Threading.WaitHandle]::WaitAny($handles,10000,$true)
    if ($h -eq 258) {
        $callback = {
            (New-Object System.Threading.ManualResetEvent($false)).Set()
        }
        foreach ($y in $pipelines) {
            # Every pipline that is still open should be terminated immediately 
            $y.BeginStop($callback,$null)
        }
        continue
    }
    $handle = $handles.Item($h)
    $job = $jobs.Item($h)
    $pipeline = $pipelines.Item($h)
    $res += $pipeline.EndInvoke($job)
    $handles.RemoveAt($h)
    $jobs.RemoveAt($h)
    $pipelines.RemoveAt($h)
    $handle.Dispose()
    $pipeline.Dispose()
}
$pool.Close()
```

Comment: What kind of commands do you run in runspaces?

Comment: They require Snap-In to be loaded, they are Citrix commands to query the service statuses of a Citrix instance. There is no way to adjust the timeout of the commands as far as I know.

Comment: http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2010/01/01/cancelling-a-pipeline.aspx

Comment: So, commands are compiled cmdlets. Then them have to check [`Cmdlet.Stopping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.automation.cmdlet.stopping.aspx) and/or override [`Cmdlet.StopProcessing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.automation.cmdlet.stopprocessing.aspx) to properly react to pipeline stopping event. If them does not do that, then you likely out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

This Script check if some App-pole Stop  $SourcePath it's IIS application path

```
param (
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $true)]
    $SourcePath

)
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

try {
    write-host  $SourcePath
    $SourcePath=$SourcePath -replace(':','$')
    write-host  $SourcePath
    $LASTEXITCODE =1
    exit $LASTEXITCODE

}Catch{
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
    write-verbose "Error: '$ErrorMessage' - on item: '$FailedItem'"  -verbose
    Break
}



#Jenkins Pipeline Catch exception from Powershell 
def ComponentPath =params.ComponentPath
def libName = 'Devops'
def slnPath = "C:/${libName}"
node {

   stage('test'){

  def status =   powershell returnStatus: true, script: "${slnPath}/deploy_scripts/BackUpBeforeDeployM.ps1  -SourcePath ${ComponentPath}"
     if (status == 0) {
        println 'Success!'
    }else
    {

      error("iis check failed")


    }

}
}
```